# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'rectange'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am using the following code on python 3.7

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\\ET\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('D:\\ET\\haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectange(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the following is installed:

```
opencv-contrib-python-3.4.4.19
```

Comment: can you please provide the full traceback in the post?

Comment: cv2.rectange(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-44-27e5a77b290d>", line 1, in <module>
    cv2.rectange(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'rectange'

Comment: can I delete the question? it was a very stupid error

Comment: yes, if it was a typo, you can [delete question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question)

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that cv2 doesn't have anything called `rectange`, but it does have something called [`rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle). You misspelled it:

```
cv2.rectange(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```